# Progammically change multiple buttons with for loop C#

Tags: c#, button, for-loop

Im trying to do something like this:

```
list<int> listName = new list<int>();

for(int i; i <= listName[0];i++)
{
    button(i).Enabled = false;
}
```

... to disable all buttons from 1 to i.
What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can put all the buttons inside a container like a panel and disable the panel instead of looping

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't know what is `button` exactly but I don't think `(i)` will work.. Read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: What is the variable `button`?

Comment: This looks like before this code happens, you placed your buttons in an array called `button`? If it is you should use `button[i]`

Comment: To make everything clear, the buttons are simply some buttons in a windows form. They are called "button1", "button2" etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to bulk modify controls.

**Example 1 (putting them all in a list)**

```
List<Button> buttonsToDisable = new List<Button>()
{
    button1, 
    button2
};

foreach (var button in buttonsToDisable)
{
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

---

**Example 2 (putting them in the same container then iterating over the controls in that container)**

```
foreach(var button in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

---

**Example 3 (subfixing your controls with an id)**

```
List<int> buttonSubfixId = new List<int>()
{
    1,
    2
};

foreach (var id in buttonSubfixId)
{
    var controls = this.Controls.Find("button" + id.ToString(), true).OfType<Button>();

    if (controls.Count()>0)
    {
        foreach (var button in controls)
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aww. I did an edit on your post which was wrong. Just ignore it dude. This solution is right. Upvoted.